# android recyclerview notifyItemInserted animation

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I don't know why this behaviour is happening, but calling `notifyItemInserted(0)` (first position only) won't animate the view. Everything works fine in another positions.

Animation working in this case:

```
friendsList.remove(positionFriend);
friendsList.add(1, newFriend);
notifyItemInserted(1);
notifyItemRemoved(positionFriend+1);
```

Animation not working in this case:

```
friendsList.remove(positionFriend);
friendsList.add(0, newFriend);
notifyItemInserted(0);
notifyItemRemoved(positionFriend+1);
```

Expected behaviour: Element inserted at the top and insert animation happens there.

What is happening: No insert animation is shown, actually i think 'visually', first element disappears and move animation happens.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

the animation happens. But your old position zero becomes position 1 (visible on the screen) and the new position zero appears if you scroll up. So to make it visible you have to scroll the recycler afterwards.

```
friendsList.remove(positionFriend);
friendsList.add(0, newFriend);
notifyItemInserted(0);
notifyItemRemoved(positionFriend+1);
recycler.scrollToPosition(0);
```

Comment: oh, thats why the elements are moved. It's a weird behaviour, and your fix should be native ... One last thing, any way to do recycler.scrollToPosition(0) without passing a reference in adapters constructor?

Comment: I agree it's a weird behavior from a user point of view, but if you imagined how the RecyclerView is coded in the back, it's just a logical behavior. Not that I'm aware of, I usually call `notify_` from outside the adapter, and let the adapter be just the data list and the bindView code.